# Add Application to IIS Web Site programmatically (or in web.config)

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

Is there a way to add a sub/child application to an existing IIS Web Site?

I know this can be done by the IIS Admin Gui but in some CMS'es like EPiServer this can be done by config. Somehow creating a virtual application instance inside the current IIS Web Site.

[image: Add application]

Any advice or reference to how to solve this or where to start is highly appreciated. Im using IIS 7.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using command line. You could create a batch file and run it as a post-deploy event.

This is the general syntax (you can find more info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)):

```
appcmd add app /site.name: string /path: string /physicalPath: string
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using Windows PowerShell.

Following Script Commands should do the trick

**
Import-Module WebAdministration
set-location iis:\
new-item "iis:\Sites\Default Web Site\appname" -physicalpath "physicalpath"  -type Application -force**

Where ***appname*** is the name of application you want to add and ***physicalpath*** should be the path to content of web application.

For detail information please visit 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867899.aspx